# I am having trouble getting the average ages of employees

Tags: java

[image: This is the problem]

My source code is as follows: 
I used the file reader method to obtain all files from a list of employees saved on notepad. My code has no syntax errors but for some reason, both variables age and salary are not used and the average age is not being calculated from the employee list but rather from the values which i initialized age to;0. Any suggestions?

```
public EmployeeAverage() {
    Container contentPane;

    File file;
    FileReader fileReader = null;
    BufferedReader buffReader;

    file = new File("C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\Codefile\\code\\employees.txt");
    try {
        fileReader = new FileReader(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Cannot open employees file");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    buffReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

    ArrayList employees = new ArrayList();
    String line = "";
    String first;
    String last;
    String SSN;
    int age=0;
    double salary=0;
    int lineCount = 0;

    while (true) {
        try {
        line = buffReader.readLine();
        if (line == null)
            break;
        lineCount++;
        first = line;
        line = buffReader.readLine(); lineCount++;
        last = line;
        line = buffReader.readLine(); lineCount++;
        SSN = line;
        line = buffReader.readLine(); lineCount++;
        line=Integer.toString(age);
        line = buffReader.readLine(); lineCount++;
        line=Double.toString(salary);
        } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Data file error at line "+lineCount);
        System.err.println("Ignoring rest of file");
        break;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.err.println("Illegal age or salary at line "+lineCount);
        System.err.println("Ignoring rest of file");
        break;
        }
        employees.add(new Employee(first, last, SSN, age, salary));
    }
    System.out.println("Number of employees: " + employees.size());

    Collections.sort(employees);

    // when we get here, employees refers to a sorted employee list

    setSize(300,500);
    setTitle("Employee Averages");
    //setLocation(150,250);

    contentPane = getContentPane();
    contentPane.setBackground(Color.white);
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    // Create a panel for the employee list
    JPanel employeeList = new JPanel();
    employeeList.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    employeeList.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Employees"));

    // Create the employee list, make it into a scroll pane, and
    // add it to the employee list panel
    list = new JList(employees.toArray());
    JScrollPane employeeChooser = new JScrollPane(list);
    employeeList.add(employeeChooser, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    // Create the radio buttons
    // Ignore this until you finish Checkpoint 2.

    // Create a text area to show the average
    avg = new JTextArea("");

    // Now put both the employee list and the average
    // into the top-level pane
    contentPane.add(employeeList, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    contentPane.add(avg,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    // Monitor changes in the employee list selection
    list.addListSelectionListener(this);

    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
    displayAverage();
    }

    public void displayAverage() {

    if (list == null)
        return; // don't do anything if there is no list yet

    Object [] selectedEmployees = list.getSelectedValues();
    int len = selectedEmployees.length;
    if (len == 0) {
        avg.setText("");
        return;
    }

    DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("#0.0");

    int sum = 0;
    for (int i=0 ; i<len ; i++) {
        Employee emp = (Employee)selectedEmployees[i];
        sum += emp.getAge();
    }
    avg.setText("Average age = " + fmt.format((double)sum/len));
    }
}
```

[image: This is the employees list used by the file reader method]

Comment: I tried already. Still no luck

Comment: Please produce a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). With a little luck, while doing that, you could discover what the error is. And if you still don’t, we’ll be happy to look at the minimal example instead of the masses of code you’ve given us now.

Answer (score 2):

What do you expect these lines to do?

```
line=Integer.toString(age);
line=Double.toString(salary);
```

It looks like you got it backwads. You should parse the `int` `age` and `double` `salary` from the input lines :

```
line = buffReader.readLine(); lineCount++;
age=Integer.parseInt(line);
line = buffReader.readLine(); lineCount++;
salary=Double.parseDouble(line);
```

Comment: well i got a syntax error stating that the string variable line could not be converted to int. That is why i used the Integer.toString() object.

Comment: @MichaelM. You were trying to convert the 0 valued `age` and `salary` variables to `String` and assign them to your `line` variable. I don't see the point. You are supposed to do the opposite - read the input line from the file and convert it to int (to get the age) or double (to get the salary).

Comment: I see where you are getting at. It explains why it was not reading values from the list but rather from the code itself. Thank you for that. You've been a great help